# How to animate a div scrolling to its last child on page load using JS?

Tags: javascript, css, scroll

I am trying to get an animation of a div scrolling down to its last child when the page is loaded to create a slide show.

Here is the div itself

```
<section class="carousel" id="carousel">
  <div class="images-container">
    <a href="#"><img src="img/berlin1.jpg" alt="pic 1" class="auto-resize"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="img/berlin2.jpg" alt="pic 1" class="auto-resize"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="img/berlin3.jpg" alt="pic 1" class="auto-resize"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="img/berlin4.jpg" alt="pic 1" class="auto-resize"></a>
    <a href="#" id="lastimage"><img src="img/berlin5.jpg" alt="pic 1" class="auto-resize"></a>
  </div>
</section>
```

```
.carousel {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  grid-area: crsl;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none;
}

.carousel::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 0 !important }
```

Ultimately what I am trying to achieve is an automatic slideshow in this div when the page loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need the scroll bar besides the automatic slide show you could remove the scrollbar by giving the div min-content height and then using a translateY transform and a transition to make the images slide through your section.

I've set up an example:

```js
let imagesContainer = document.getElementById("images-container");
let lastImgHeight = 0;
window.onload = () => {
    lastImgHeight = document.getElementById("last-img").clientHeight;
    document.getElementById("carousel").style.maxHeight = `${lastImgHeight}px`;
};

setTimeout(() => {
    imagesContainer.classList.add("images-container-animate");
    imagesContainer.classList.remove("images-container");
    imagesContainer.style.transform = `translateY(${-(imagesContainer.clientHeight - lastImgHeight)}px)`;
}, 100);
```

```css
.images-container {
 height: min-content;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 transform: translateY(0);
}

.images-container-animate {
 transition: transform 6s;
 transition-timing-function: linear;
        display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}

#carousel {
 overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

```html
<section class="carousel" id="carousel">
  <div class="images-container" id="images-container">
    <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/03/10/08/39/cloud-4918228_960_720.jpg"
        alt="pic 1"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/03/30/17/15/funes-4984899_960_720.jpg"
        alt="pic 1"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/03/31/11/59/sunrise-4987384_960_720.jpg"
        alt="pic 1" id="last-img"></a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: That seems to be the solution. How can I make it so the images slide down from top to bottom and stop at the last one?

Comment: To achieve that you have to manipulate the image-container class and the carousel. The carousel max-height has to be the height of the last image and images-container-animnate translateY has to be the height of the images-container minus height of the last image. You can achieve that by setting these values statically in your css code or whats better, you could set them dynamically in javascript. I would go with the second one of these options because then you can change your images and don't need to modify the css code. I've edited the above code to your needs.